# Gulp - Run tasks once per folder

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm using Gulp to automate the production of banner ads. I have a list of folders (`project.banners`) and a set of tasks that should be **run on each folder**.

With my limited knowledge of Gulp I can not figure out how to do this automatically. For now I have to manually update the `var banner` to point to one particular folder.

I know there are several similar questions on StackOverflow, but could not find anyone that fit or solved my problem, and my trials with a forEach loop has only resulted in errors.

Example:

```
// Settings
var project = {
    title       : "Client - Project",
    devPath     : "dev/client/banner/", 
    banners : [
        "180x500",
        "580x400",
        "468x468"
    ]
}

// Choose which banner/folder to Gulp (should be set by a loop!!?)
var banner = project.banners[0]; 

// Run tasks
gulp.task('default', function(callback) {
    runSequence(
        'css', 
        'html',
        'zip',
        callback
    );
});

// Example task
gulp.task('css', function() {
  return gulp.src(devPath + banner + '/style.css')   
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/temp/' + banner + '/'))
});
```

Comment: Can you just put a `gulpfile` in each folder and use a `bash` loop?

Comment: I would like to keep one gulpfile, easier to maintain, and not sure what a bash loop is.

Comment: Did you try wrapping the content of your task within a `for` loop that iterates over the content of banners and removing the `return`? Not sure if this will still play nicely with `runSequence`. But a way around `runSequence` would be to define dependencies for each of your tasks that are being run in sequence.

Comment: What errors do you get when you try a `for` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the indications found on the [official gulp recipe](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/running-task-steps-per-folder.md) I think something like this should work, but I have yet to test it.

```
// ...
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

// ...

function getFolders(dir) {
    return fs.readdirSync(dir)
      .filter(function(file) {
        return fs.statSync(path.join(dir, file)).isDirectory();
      });
}

gulp.task('banners', function() {
  // get all folders inside project.devPath, if you need specific 
  // folders maybe you should wrap them inside another
  var folders = getFolders(project.devPath);

  return folders.map(function(folder) {
    // .map runs this action on each folder and returns the stream
    return gulp.src(project.debPath + folder + '/style.js')
      .pipe(minifycss())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/temp/' + folder + '/'));
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it's much smarter to automatically read the folder names, than to write them in an array, but this example doesn't seem to solve the problem with running a defined set of tasks multiple times. Can I combine this with `runSequence`?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably generate a new task for each banner dimension and call them separately in you default task.

```
project.banners.forEach(function (banner /* <- this will be "180x500" the first time, "580x400" the next time etc. */ ) {
  gulp.task(banner, function () {
    return gulp.src(devPath + banner + '/style.css')   
      .pipe(minifycss())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/temp/' + banner + '/'));
  });
});
```

Then in your default task run:

```
runSequence.apply(this, project.banners.concat(['html', 'zip', callback]));
```

Doing .apply() will send the array as seperate arguments

Comment: Thanks, this makes it possible to run multiple tasks, but it doesn't solve the problem with variable path/foldername. I still have to define the path (`var banner = project.banners[0];`), if not the tasks fail.

Comment: No.. the banner parameter passed to the forEach callback will be a reference to the relevant folder name. See my updated example.
But Manuel's version is a much better solution.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, I ended up doing this:

1. Loop through all banners and call a custom function ('createBanner') with banner as variable.
2. Create tasks with dynamic tasknames inside function.
3. Run tasks in sequence.

   ```
   // Settings
   var project = {
       title       : "Client - Project",
       devPath     : "dev/client/banner/", 
       banners : [ 
           // Array with banners (= folder names)
           "180x500",
           "580x400",
           "468x468"
       ]
   }

   // Place all tasks inside this function - receives banner/foldername
   function createBanner(banner) {

       // Example task - with dynamic taskname
       gulp.task('css_' +  banner, function() {
         return gulp.src(devPath + banner + '/style.css')   
           .pipe(minifycss())
           .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/temp/' + banner + '/'))
       });  

       // ... Other tasks

       // Run tasks in sequence
       runSequence(
           'css_' + banner,
           'html_' + banner,
           'zip_' + banner
       );        

   }          

   // Default task
   gulp.task('default', function(callback) {

       // Loop through all banners - call function with current banner as variable
       for (var i = 0; i < project.banners.length; i++) {
           createBanner(project.banners[i]);
       };

   });
   ```